# Insert serialVersionUID with ANT

Tags: serialization, ant, build, suid

Is it possible to use an ANT task to insert the serialVersionUID property into all classes that implement Serializable?

I would like to be able to keep a list of classes vs SUIDs and use that to insert values.

Currently the source code does not have teh serialVersionUID set.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Ant External Tools and Tasks sit](http://ant.apache.org/external.html)e has a [SerialVer Task](http://serialver.sourceforge.net/) listed.

Comment: I cannot find any examples or documentation on how to use this to insert the property.